# How to use other language libraries/frameworks with lua?

Tags: java, lua

I *really* like Lua. It's like javascript without so many warts.

 One thing I hate about Lua is the 3rd party support. Good luck finding any industrial-grade libraries or frameworks with Lua scripting - Unity 3d has javascript, but no Lua. Qt the same.

 I'm wondering if there is a way to "bridge" an arbirtary Lua & some other application. Say, I want 2 programs running - Lua interpreter which handles all the fun stuff, and Java VM which recieves GUI information from Lua (and displays a Swing GUI) and sends user input to Lua.

EDIT: For clarification what I really really want.

From what I remember from CS101, every program has a standard input and output. Is it possible to have:

- Two programs running, 1st in the foreground (java VM), 2nd in background (lua interpreter). I mean, the 2nd one doesn't appear in the task bar. I'm not sure if that's possible, I'm no systems programmer :).

- Java stdin: gui description data + say, glCanvas or some other graphics data. Stdout: user input. Lua's stdin is joined with Java's stdout and vice versa.


I would thank for a code sample if possible. 

EDIT: Nevermind, what I looked for was Inter Process Communication.

Answer (score 2):

You can embed, for example, [LuaJ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/luaj/) in your Java app. Then you will be able to write any logic on Lua and some other things on Java.

Also, you can take a look on projects like kahlua and mochalua (both hosts on googlecode).

Comment: Thanks for your time, but what I want is to , hm, 'join' lua interpreter's standard input/output with the java VM's. I just don't know where to begin with this.